# accessing the Litecoin testnet

Tags: litecoin, testnet, litecoin-qt

I am very new to creation of cryptocurrency wallet. how to create and access the litecoin testnet and elaborate the available ways to do that?if possible, provide link to simple sample project.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, do you want to run a full node and store the entire blockchain? You could run Litecoin Core: https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin. There are other implementations/installation options as well.

For an example of a project with a wallet, explorer, and full node, see:

https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecore

It implements:

- **Node** - A full node with extended capabilities using Litecoin Core
- **Insight Lite API** - A blockchain explorer HTTP API
- **Insight Lite UI** - A blockchain explorer web user interface
- **Wallet Service** - A multisig HD service for wallets
- **Wallet Client** - A client for the wallet service
- **CLI Wallet** - A command-line based wallet client
- **Angular Wallet Client** - An Angular based wallet client
- **Copay** - An easy-to-use, multiplatform, multisignature, secure bitcoin wallet

Comment: thanks for your time. is above steps are initial steps to learn from scratch?

Comment: how can I open the github project?in visual studio code?

Comment: What do you mean? You can clone the repository, then add the folder to your workspace.